# How can I calculate Line scan camera Depth of Field (DOF)

Tags: computer-vision

I have an image processing project. I will calculate the best `DOF` parameter. I have researched about this topic. I found that `DOF` related to four parameters:

*1)Circle of confusion (COC)

2)Aperture of the lens

3)Lens focal length

4)Focus distance (distance between lens and subject)*

My goal is to have clearest image in distance range which I write below.

How can I calculate the most suitable four parameters?
Can anyone give me formulas which makes me perform calculation?

Camera:raL2048-48gm,
Lenses:Kowa-LM50SC,
Imagesize:1x2048 pixel,
Objectdistance min:50cm, max:60cm

Thank you for interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/is-there-a-formula-to-calculate-dof

this will work I hope, but I cant see any other answers in here